# SQL query on server returns SQL Error while on localhost works fine

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following SQL query

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Log` (
      `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `customer_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `request_xml` BLOB NOT NULL,
      `response_xml` LONGBLOB NOT NULL,
      `timestamp_process_end` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      `timestamp_response` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    );
```

could someone see any mistakes? Because it gives me a SQL Error when I run the code on server. But on localhost works without any problems (or phpmyadmin)

And btw this works on the server:

```
     CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lang` (
      `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `language` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL UNIQUE,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    );
```

that is written in the same style. Any remarks?

LE: Mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.73

Comment: in the first query I get just USER ERROR(256): "SQL Error" ..I don't have access to Logs or other stuff

Comment: Do you have permission of creating table?

Comment: I assume yes, once the second query works.

Comment: You cannot use two timestamp in one table with not null type.

Comment: and why works on localhost server? or maybe you want to elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the problem was that on the remote server I couldn't have two DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, as stated here [mysql link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html), but this is wired that on the localhost worked.